# Devise Login Validation: Include Current URL in Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

I was wondering if there is a way to include checking the current URL during login with devise.

Say that I have a user model with field :url, and that along with :email and :password, you also check if the current url matches with the user's :url field.

I was thinking I should do this in devise's self.find_for_database_authentication method and I currently have this:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login).downcase
      where(conditions).where('$or' => [{:username => /^#{Regexp.escape(login)}$/i}, {:email => /^#{Regexp.escape(login)}$/i}]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```

but what should I add to it so that it checks the current URL?

Note: I am using mongoid

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just being curious here: why would you want to check for the request url? This will not make the system more secure.

Comment: I want to emulate an existing site's login system: they provide a sign in URL on registration and you use that URL to go to sign in page and then use your email and password to sign in via a form.

Comment: if you have another approach to checking that I am pretty much open to other solutions :)

Comment: Well i think i dont understand your intention. Why is the combination of user/pass not enough? Isnt the login url always the same?

Comment: no. for example, user x can log in at mysite/xlogin. and user y can log in at mysite/ylogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add the url to the query, something like this:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  login = conditions.delete(:login).downcase
  url   = conditions.delete(:url  ).downcase

  if login && url
    where(conditions).where(
      :url => {"$eq" => url},
      '$or' => [
        {:username => /^#{Regexp.escape(login)}$/i},
        {:email    => /^#{Regexp.escape(login)}$/i}
      ]
    ).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

Where the hash it is sort of an implicit "and"